SQL joining column from same table
I need to create a view from the table by joining the columns from the same table.
Here is how my table has been created
CREATE TABLE tbl (emp VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, col1 VARCHAR, col2 VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('one', 'A','B');
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('two', 'B',NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('three', 'D',NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('four', NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('five', NULL,NULL);

which looks like this, the empty value in the following table denotes the NULL
D SELECT * FROM tbl;
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│   emp   │  col1   │  col2   │
│ varchar │ varchar │ varchar │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ one     │ A       │ B       │
│ two     │ B       │         │
│ three   │ D       │         │
│ four    │         │         │
│ five    │         │         │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

The view I need is the cross product of the first column with the rest ones and should look like
D SELECT * FROM out;
┌─────────┬─────────┐
│   emp   │   col   │
│ varchar │ varchar │
├─────────┼─────────┤
│ one     │ A       │
│ one     │ B       │
│ two     │ B       │
│ three   │ D       │
└─────────┴─────────┘


what dbms are you using?

Sidenote: Your example is unlucky. Do you have other strings in the first column and simplified them as "numbers"? Or do you really have such strings there? If it's just a simplification, it would be good to mention this in the question. If not, you would do far better to use an int column and store real numbers. This would for example allow to apply sorting.

You can use UNION ALL like this
CREATE VIEW <viewName> AS
SELECT emp, col1 AS col FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT emp, col2 AS col FROM tbl WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL;


Worth mentioning that UNION ALL is preferred because is much faster than UNION, in terms of performance

Maybe add ORDER BY col to make sure the result is sorted as shown in the question

Thank you ORDER is necessary for my use case.

SELECT emp, col1 AS col FROM tbl WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT emp, col2 as col FROM tbl WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL


A bit too late, but the question was about self joining so here is one of the options:
Join it ON(1=1) And use Case expressions to select data:
SELECT   DISTINCT  
              Case When EMP_2_COL Is Not Null Then EMP_2 Else EMP_1 End "EMP", 
              Case When EMP_2_COL Is Not Null Then EMP_2_COL Else EMP_1_COL End "COL"
FROM         ( Select  EMP "EMP_1", COL1 "EMP_1_COL" From tbl ) t1
INNER  JOIN  ( Select  EMP "EMP_2", COL2 "EMP_2_COL" From tbl ) t2 ON(1=1) 
WHERE        Case When EMP_2_COL Is Not Null Then EMP_2_COL Else EMP_1_COL End Is Not Null
ORDER BY     COL, EMP

/*    R e s u l t :
EMP                              COL                 
-------------------------------- --------------------
one                              A                   
one                              B                   
two                              B                   
three                            D                  */


The OP doesn't state limitations. In this case this over-complicates the view.

Why use CASE and not simply COALESCE?

@JonasMetzler Because there is no database tag ....

@ErgestBasha Agreed. This was just because of the title and text of the question asking about self join...

@dr COALESCE is standard SQL and should work in every RDBMS. If a RDBMS does not support it, I would not use it and would doubt it supports other standard SQL like CASE ;)
